# access DOM in polymer

Tags: dom, module, polymer

What I want to achieve:

1. highlight some text in p element
2. (not add/ or remove) paper-badge when value is 0
3. change paper-badge color depending on number

Sample module to play with:

```
<link rel="import" href="https://polygit2.appspot.com/components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://polygit2.appspot.com/components/iron-icons/communication-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://polygit2.appspot.com/components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://polygit2.appspot.com/components/paper-badge/paper-badge.html">

<dom-module id="question-one">
    <template>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{numbers}}">
            <p>color one of my letters</p>
            <paper-icon-button id="someid{{index}}" icon="communication:email"></paper-icon-button>
            <paper-badge for="someid{{index}}" label="{{item}}"> </paper-badge>
        </template>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: "question-one",
            properties: {
                numbers: {
                    type: Array,
                    value: function () {
                        return [0, 1, 2, 0, 4, 5, 0, 7, 8, 0]
                    }
                }
            }
        }); </script>
</dom-module>
```

and usage:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://polygit2.appspot.com/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="questions//question-one.html" />
</head>
<body>
    <question-one></question-one>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For reference, working with DOM is documented here: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom#dom-api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an `id` attribute

```
<p id="someId">
```

use the `$` map to get a reference to the element

```
this.$.someId.innerText...
```

`this.$` doesn't work for dynamically added HTML or HTML inside `template is="dom-if" or`template is="dom-repeat" or similar.

For such cases you can use `this.$$(selector)` where all CSS selectors are supported, while `this.$...` only supports `id` (without `#`)